# KDB Table Pivot reverse engineering problem

Tags: kdb

In KDB, I have a simple table that I am trying to pivot. Using the https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/ I am still lost. I am a newbie to KDB.
I have a table

```
t:([]sym:`IBM`FB`TESLA`IBM;exchange:`A`A`B`B;OB_p1:4#100.1;OB_p2:100.2 100.2 100.3 100.4;OB_p3:100.5 100.6 100.7 100.8;OB_p4:100.8 100.8 100.8 100.9)

sym     exchange  OB_p1  OB_p2  OB_p3   OB_p4
IBM     A         100.1  100.2  100.5   100.8
FB      A         100.1  100.2  100.6   100.8
TESLA   B         100.1  100.3  100.7   100.8
IBM     B         100.1  100.4  100.8   100.9
```

I am trying to create the following table:

```
exchange OB    IBM   FB  TESLA 
A        OB_1  
A        OB_1
B        OB_1
```

I was wondering if there is anyone who could kindly assist in this task? I have tried the pivot table recommendation on https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/ with no luck

Answer (score 3):

Sample table:

```
t:flip `sym`exchange`OB_p1`OB_p2`OB_p3`OB_p4!flip (
    (`IBM;`A;100.1;100.2;100.5;100.8);
    (`FB;`A;100.1;100.2;100.6;100.8);
    (`TESLA;`B;100.1;100.3;100.7;100.8);
    (`IBM;`B;100.1;100.4;100.8;100.9))
```

Gives:

```
sym   exchange OB_p1 OB_p2 OB_p3 OB_p4
--------------------------------------
IBM   A        100.1 100.2 100.5 100.8
FB    A        100.1 100.2 100.6 100.8
TESLA B        100.1 100.3 100.7 100.8
IBM   B        100.1 100.4 100.8 100.9
```

`unpivot` function taken from https://gist.github.com/rianoc/a14b832f12908c4785e2297995db1e76

```
unpivot:{[tab;baseCols;pivotCols;kCol;vCol] 
 base:?[tab;();0b;{x!x}(),baseCols];
 newCols:{[k;v;t;p] flip (k;v)!(count[t]#p;t p)}[kCol;vCol;tab] each pivotCols;
 baseCols xasc raze {[b;n] b,'n}[base] each newCols
 }
```

Calling:

```
t:unpivot[t;`sym`exchange;`OB_p1`OB_p2`OB_p3`OB_p4;`OB;`val]
```

Gives:

```
sym   exchange OB    val  
--------------------------
FB    A        OB_p1 100.1
FB    A        OB_p2 100.2
FB    A        OB_p3 100.6
FB    A        OB_p4 100.8
IBM   A        OB_p1 100.1
IBM   A        OB_p2 100.2
IBM   A        OB_p3 100.5
IBM   A        OB_p4 100.8
IBM   B        OB_p1 100.1
IBM   B        OB_p2 100.4
IBM   B        OB_p3 100.8
IBM   B        OB_p4 100.9
TESLA B        OB_p1 100.1
TESLA B        OB_p2 100.3
TESLA B        OB_p3 100.7
TESLA B        OB_p4 100.8
```

`piv` function taken from https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/

`f` from link simplified for this usecase when naming pivoted columns

```
piv:{[t;k;p;v;f;g]
 v:(),v;
 G:group flip k!(t:.Q.v t)k;
 F:group flip p!t p;
 count[k]!g[k;P;C]xcols 0!key[G]!flip(C:f[v]P:flip value flip key F)!raze
  {[i;j;k;x;y]
   a:count[x]#x 0N;
   a[y]:x y;
   b:count[x]#0b;
   b[y]:1b;
   c:a i;
   c[k]:first'[a[j]@'where'[b j]];
   c}[I[;0];I J;J:where 1<>count'[I:value G]]/:\:[t v;value F]}

f:{[v;P]P[;0]} 
g:{[k;P;c]k,(raze/)flip flip each 5 cut'10 cut raze reverse 10 cut asc c}
```

Calling:

```
piv[t;`exchange`OB;(),`sym;(),`val;f;g]
```

Gives:

```
exchange OB   | FB    IBM   TESLA
--------------| -----------------
A        OB_p1| 100.1 100.1      
A        OB_p2| 100.2 100.2      
A        OB_p3| 100.6 100.5      
A        OB_p4| 100.8 100.8      
B        OB_p1|       100.1 100.1
B        OB_p2|       100.4 100.3
B        OB_p3|       100.8 100.7
B        OB_p4|       100.9 100.8
```

Comment: Thank you rian. This really helped. I was able to decompress the table. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rians answer is a more general approach but this should help you understand the manipulation:

```
q)ungroup exec((`FB`IBM`TESLA!3#0n),sym!flip(OB_p1;OB_p2;OB_p3;OB_p4))by exchange,OB:count[i]#enlist`OB_p1`OB_p2`OB_p3`OB_p4 from t
exchange OB    FB    IBM   TESLA
--------------------------------
A        OB_p1 100.1 100.1
A        OB_p2 100.2 100.2
A        OB_p3 100.6 100.5
A        OB_p4 100.8 100.8
B        OB_p1       100.1 100.1
B        OB_p2       100.4 100.3
B        OB_p3       100.8 100.7
B        OB_p4       100.9 100.8
```

In a functional form it would be:

```
q)c:cols[t]where cols[t]like"*OB*";
q)s:exec distinct sym from t;
q)ungroup ?[t;();`exchange`OB!(`exchange;(#;(count;`i);enlist enlist c));(,;s!count[s]#0n;(!;`sym;(flip;enlist,c)))]
exchange OB    IBM   FB    TESLA
--------------------------------
A        OB_p1 100.1 100.1
A        OB_p2 100.2 100.2
A        OB_p3 100.5 100.6
A        OB_p4 100.8 100.8
B        OB_p1 100.1       100.1
B        OB_p2 100.4       100.3
B        OB_p3 100.8       100.7
B        OB_p4 100.9       100.8
```